# Chebyshev Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory

Given 
$$-\frac{1}2<a<\alpha<0<\beta<b<+\frac{1}2$$
$$+\frac{1}2<c<\gamma<1<\delta<d<+\frac{3}2$$
 I want to find a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ such that $f([a,b])\subseteq[\alpha,\beta]$,  $f([c,d])\subseteq[\gamma,\delta]$. What is minimum degree polynomial that is needed and maximum degree that will suffice?

I believe Chebyshev polynomials play a role here. What is degree as function of $a,b,c,d,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ that is necessary and sufficient using Chebyshev polynomials?

Is there an explicit formula (not a computational solution) that gives a good enough answer within constants?

Comment: Is that second $-1/2$ supposed to be $+1/2$?  And the $0$ supposed to be $1$?

Comment: Still not quite right: $1/2 < \ldots < 0$?

Comment: corrected both $+$, $1$ values.

Answer (score 9):

Such polynomials were studied in my papers with Peter Yuditskii:

Uniform approximation of sgn(x) by polynomials and entire functions, J. d'Analyse Math., 101 (2007) 313-324, and

Polynomials of the best uniform approximation to sgn(x) on two intervals, J. d'Analyse math., 114 (2011) 285-315.

We obtained asymptotic estimates (when the degree is large, $\beta-\alpha$ and $\delta-\gamma$ small. But it is clear from these papers how to obtain minimal degree for given
$a,b,\alpha,\beta,c,d,\gamma,\delta$ in the cases when this degree is not large, using a computer. We have pictures of some extremal polynomials, and some representation of them.

Comment: Thank you could you summarize the degree dependency on $a,\dots,\delta$ for completeness?

Comment: Both papers are available on the arxiv.